# How to make a double door?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was trying to make a double door that would open fully (both doors) if one was opened, and close fully if one was closed (by right-clicking, not by buttons).

**How can I make a double door like this?**

A compact way of doing this would be good, and I don't mind using command blocks, though redstone would be better.

Comment: its been a while since ive played minecraft, but cant you just connect redstone from each side of the door to the same pressure plate?

Comment: I don't see a link to a picture.

Comment: @ZeroStack They want this to work with right clicking, not just buttons/pressure plates.

Comment: Yep. No Pressure plates, no buttons, no levers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution with command blocks:

[image: The contraption from the front above]

What the numbers are:

1. `/testforblock ~ ~+3 ~ minecraft:door C`
2. `/testforblock ~ ~+3 ~ minecraft:door C`
3. `/setblock XR YR ZR minecraft:wooden_door O`
4. `/setblock XL YL ZL minecraft:wooden_door O`
5. `/setblock XR YR ZR minecraft:wooden_door C`
6. `/setblock XL YL ZL minecraft:wooden_door C`

And what the letters are:

- **`XR`**, **`YR`**, **`ZR`** are the coordinates of the **R**ight door
- **`XL`**, **`YL`**, **`ZL`** are the coordinates of the **L**eft door
- `O` and `C` are the door state numbers. `O` stands for open, `C` for closed. Instead of these two numbers, use:

  - O = 4, C = 0 when the doors are facing east (positive X)
  - O = 5, C = 1 when the doors are facing south (positive Z)
  - O = 6, C = 2 when the doors are facing west (negative X)
  - O = 7, C = 3 when the doors are facing north (negative Z)

You can tell which way the door is facing by pressing <kbd>F3</kbd> and pointing at it:

[image: How to use F3]

Note in the screenshot that you are looking west, too, even though the door is on the closer side of the block to you.